# matrix by matrix in R markdown

Tags: r, matrix, markdown

I want to have multiple matrices side by side to present spectral decomposition in R markdown, but it doesn't seem to work. Please help

```
$$
\left(\begin{array}
0.8944272 & 0.4472136\\
-0.4472136 & -0.8944272
\end{array}\right\)

\left(\begin{array}
10 & 0\\
0 & 5
\end{array}\right)
$$
```

Comment: I think that this question belongs to LaTeX forum indeed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Three minor corrections should be sufficient to make this work for both, HTML and PDF output:

1. remove the backslash before the closing bracket in `\right\)`
2. delete the empty line in the middle
3. specify the column alignment in each `array` environment, e.g., with `\begin{array}{cc}`

-

```
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
0.8944272 & 0.4472136\\
-0.4472136 & -0.8944272
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
10 & 0\\ 
0 & 5
\end{array}\right)
$$
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to copy-paste this but in my case it does not render the matrices at all. I'm using Package: rmarkdown, Version: 0.9.5 Built: R 3.2.3 on Mac OS X with no success. I also noticed that I'm not able to render fractions either. Any ideas ?

Comment: @gyre I would guess that there might be something wrong with your  LaTeX installation; but I honestly don't know. If you can provide a minimal example where you encounter an error and provide the details of your installation I suggest that you ask a new question. Somebody else might be able to help. This one has been closed several months ago.

Comment: @gyre FWIW, the code snippet of this answer is part of a .Rmd file, which requires a specific header. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html

Comment: @ As stated [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#raw-tex) "the material between the begin and end tags will be interpreted as raw LaTeX, not as markdown". This supports my suspicion that you should check whether your LaTeX installation works.

Comment: it's a very strange issue in fact. I realized that I was actually writing into a github_document template. When I switched to html_document all the formulas started rendering as expected.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `*matrix` environments of [amsmath](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)

```
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0.8944272 & 0.4472136\\
-0.4472136 & -0.8944272
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
10 & 0\\ 
0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

amsmath is supported by [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) and [MathJax](http://mathjax.org/), the tools that are commonly used when converting RMarkdown to HTML or PDF.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this to get brackets instead of parentheses

```
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
10 & 0\\
0 & 5
\end{array}\right]$
```